# HMC5883L sensor with SparkFun Pi block

Tags: python, gpio, magnetometer, intel-edison

I'm trying to connect HMC5883L sensor with SparkFun Pi block and have no idea how to start!

Language : Python
MP : Intel Edison
Breakout Board : Sparkfun Pi block

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I would suggest to study similar cases that had been discussed on https://communities.intel.com/community/tech/edison/ Intel Edison forum.